# READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE permission error

Tags: android, permissions, crash, broadcastreceiver

I have created an app that monitors calls (incoming and outgoing) and during the time that phone is ringing , it shows details about the number.
**everything is fine in incoming calls** , but when user make an outgoing call app crashes with this error :

```
05-14 23:14:36.376 1427-1475/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x10 (has extras) } to ir.apptune.antispam/.CallReceiver requires android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE due to sender android (uid 1000)
```

here is the details about sdk version that i use :

```
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 22
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
```

permissions that i granted :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Also i have checked in run time if permissions are granted. and it returns 0 means yes. but still same error.
also please consider the Broadcast receiver declaration in manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".CallReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: This is my problem too. Have you find any idea?

Comment: have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 6):

READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE is privileged | signature permission and 3rd party apps cannot have this permission.

Comment: what is the solution for it?

Comment: Have anyone found its solution