# Outgoing call receiver is working in android 7.0 or more or not?

Tags: android

In my project, I have a scenario to get an outgoing call and trigger an event after 2 calls but in android 6 or 7 it's not working even I have given the `phone_state` permission.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CustomExceptionHandler(className));
    //String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);


        if (intent. getAction (). equals (Intent. ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL))
        {
            checkOutgoingCallCounter(shPreference,context);
        }

    }
```

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

`READ_PHONE_STATE` is a "dangerous" permission that must be requested at runtime.  The API to check whether you have a permission is in [`ContextCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)), but the API to request a permission is in [`ActivityCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)), so you need an `Activity` to request the permission.  A `BroadcastReceiver` can't request it.  (Off the top of my head, I don't think your `BroadcastReceiver` will even be called until the permission has been granted.  If it is, you could start an activity from there.)

Comment: I have an activity for giving dangerous permission Kevin But my application start after second call (App is in backgroud) trigger a receiver call and then transparent permission activity call.
I need to call broadcast first is it possible.??

Comment: And One More Thing Kevin, My Application is System Application so I have given this previleged permission and it's works till android 6.0
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"

But in 7.0 is't not works. Any Solution @Kevin

Comment: @SachinChauhan Sorry, I don't have any experience with `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE`.  Are you getting the same error as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43967703/read-privileged-phone-state-permission-error)?

Comment: Thanks Sir !!! READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE allows phone state permission for system application.